# Hover and Ready events at the same time in Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to get a Div to move randomly around the page and to "skip" the mouse on hover. I am trying to combine .ready and .hover.
Unfortunately, the "move around" animation works fine but the .onhover once only works after the ready animation started and it's not simultaneously.

How can I get an element to be animated on hover AND to move around the dom at the same time? (Without delays). Here's my code:

```
    $("document").ready(function() { 

       animateDiv($('.ciao'));

   $(".myDiv").click(function() {
    $(this).animate({left: "+=100px"});
   });

});
```

The animateDiv function:

```
    function makeNewPosition($container) {

    // Get viewport dimensions (remove the dimension of the div)
    var h = $container.height() - 50;
    var w = $container.width() - 50;

    var nh = Math.floor(Math.random() * h);
    var nw = Math.floor(Math.random() * w);

    return [nh, nw];

}

function animateDiv($target) {
    var newq = makeNewPosition($target.parent());
    var oldq = $target.offset();
    var speed = calcSpeed([oldq.top, oldq.left], newq);

    $target.animate({
        top: newq[0],
        left: newq[1]
    }, speed, function() {
        animateDiv($target);
    });

};

function calcSpeed(prev, next) {

    var x = Math.abs(prev[1] - next[1]);
    var y = Math.abs(prev[0] - next[0]);

    var greatest = x > y ? x : y;

    var speedModifier = 0.1;

    var speed = Math.ceil(greatest / speedModifier);

    return speed;

}
```

Comment: I have copied your code to a fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/t89jz9u1. But I am not sure what you're asking for exactly? The `.ciao` div animates on load, and I don't see any hover in your code? also, what's the `. myDiv` element supposed to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a working example which shows you it works togother.

```js
(function ($) {
$("document").ready(function() { 

   animateDiv($('.ciao'));

   $(".myDiv").click(function() {
    $(this).animate({marginLeft: "+=100px"});
   });

});
$(".ciao").hover(function() {
 $(this).animate({paddingLeft: "+=10px"}, { duration: 200, queue: false });
});

function makeNewPosition($container) {

    // Get viewport dimensions (remove the dimension of the div)
    var h = $container.height() - 50;
    var w = $container.width() - 50;

    var nh = Math.floor(Math.random() * h);
    var nw = Math.floor(Math.random() * w);

    return [nh, nw];

}

function animateDiv($target) {
    var newq = makeNewPosition($target.parent());
    var oldq = $target.offset();
    var speed = calcSpeed([oldq.top, oldq.left], newq);

    $target.animate({
        top: newq[0],
        left: newq[1]
    }, { duration: speed, queue: false, complete: function() {
        animateDiv($target);
    }});

};

function calcSpeed(prev, next) {

    var x = Math.abs(prev[1] - next[1]);
    var y = Math.abs(prev[0] - next[0]);

    var greatest = x > y ? x : y;

    var speedModifier = 0.1;

    var speed = Math.ceil(greatest / speedModifier);

    return speed;

}
})(jQuery)
```

```css
.ciao {
  position: absolute;
  background-color: red;
}

.myDiv {
  background-color: yellow;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Maecenas porttitor congue massa. Fusce posuere, magna sed pulvinar ultricies, purus lectus malesuada libero, sit amet commodo magna eros quis urna.
Nunc viverra imperdiet enim. Fusce est. Vivamus a tellus.
Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Proin pharetra nonummy pede. Mauris et orci.

</div>

<div class="ciao">Hello <div class="myDiv">Click on me</div></div>
```

You need to turn off the animation queue. Documentation: http://api.jquery.com/animate/

Comment: Thanks you so much! I am new to Jquery and I didn't know about this feature, thanks a lot :)